# Lock screen music controller intent

Tags: android, android-intent, lockscreen

I am trying to open an activity when clicking on the `music controller` on the lock screen. I am using an audio player service that runs in the foreground and creates a notification.

```
val intent = Intent(this, StoryActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
)

notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
```

Clicking on the notification opens the desired activity, but clicking on the music controller opens the launch activity...

How do I link the `music controller` intent to the `StoryActivity`?

Comment: please can you share where you have problems, and update your question.

Comment: When I click the music controller in the lock screen, it takes me to the launcher activity, but I want it to go to `StoryActivity`. When I click on the foreground notification (not on lock screen), it does take me to `StoryActivity`, as shown in the code above.